# adding regex capabilities on simple cgi search

Tags: regex, perl, cgi

I have this simple cgi script working just fine but I want to add regex capabilities. is that possible? if so what I need to add. thanks.

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/perl
    read(STDIN, $buffer,$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
    @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
    foreach $pair (@pairs) {
        ($key, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
        foreach $pair (@pairs) {
            ($key, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
            $value =~ tr/+/ /;
            $value =~ s/%([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
            $formdata{$key}.= "$value";
         }
     }
    $search = $formdata{'search'};
    open(INFO, "/test/myfile");
    @array=<INFO>;
    close (INFO);
```

...code truncate

Comment: Please don't use that horrible old broken form parsing code. CGI.pm has been included with Perl for almost 15 years. There's no reason not to use its `param` function.

Comment: What does "add regex capabilities" mean when you say it?

Comment: @tadmc ex. if I want search all files with cgi extension ( *.cgi) didn't return anything. I think it's because the wild card didn't recognized.

Comment: @raindrop \*.cgi is NOT A REGEX! It is a "glob". A regex for that would be .\*.cgi

Comment: @tadmic!! you are absolutely right!! I am the one have the problem not the script :(  with .* working perfectly. thank you so very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find lines that end with ".cgi":

```
my @array = grep /\.cgi$/, <INFO>;
```

Comment: this work to get file with extension .cgi  your answer above (use .*) flexible to replace any extension. again thanks very much!